# Can I use single Let's Encrypt SSL certificate for subdomains on different servers?

Tags: ssl-certificate, centos7, lets-encrypt

Currently I'm able to get a single Let's Encrypt SSL certificate working on one server with multiple subdomains.

eg. m.example.com, www.example.com, example.com on Server A

However, in order to use eg. cdn.example.com on Server B, how can I make the implementation?

My ideas are:

(1) single certificate on Server A, containing all subdomains: cdn.example.com, m.example.com, www.example.com, example.com, then rsync it to Server B

(2) one certificate on Server A, containing: m.example.com, www.example.com, example.com

second certificate on Server B, containing only: cdn.example.com

What's the correct way or best approach to make the implementation?

I'm not sure if I'm allow to generate multiple certificates regarding to one the root domain example.com

I find that (1) is easier when it comes to renewal in case I scale to multiple servers.

Can it be done this way?  Or it's redundant?

**UPDATE:**

[same SSL certificate in two servers](https://serverfault.com/questions/172058/same-ssl-certificate-in-two-servers) **does not** fully address my question. The accepted solution partially answer that SSL cert is FQDN specific, and not machine specific.

If that's the case, isn't my proposed (1) a simplified solution?

My question is that:

Can I have a partial SSL cert containing only subdomain `cdn.example.com` but leave out the others on Server B then having another SSL cert issued for Server A with the root domain `example.com`, `www.example.com`, and `m.example.com`?

Comment: you can use the same certificate and key in multiple servers, not sure it`s the best practice though, as per documentation you can issue the "same" ( a new one with all the same sub-domains ) certificate 5 times a week see the limit's in https://letsencrypt.org/docs/rate-limits/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [same SSL certificate in two servers](http://serverfault.com/questions/172058/same-ssl-certificate-in-two-servers)

Comment: "Can I have a partial SSL cert containing only subdomain cdn.example.com but leave out the others on Server B then having another SSL cert issued for Server A with the root domain" How did this work out for you?

Comment: @PJBrunet It does work.  Using (2) mentioned above, I have multiple micro VPS instances sharing the same SSL cert for cdn.example.com to distribute the workload.

Comment: @KDX OK, I was hoping to use different certificates for each subdomain/server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMHO,
Each server should have it's own private key, you can issue as many certs as you like with LE, the only reason I can think of to use multiple SANs per IP is if your clients cannot do SNI (example: old java clients if you're using webhooks/api's or other endpoints).

TLDR; option 2, just don't forget to set your auto-renewal cronjobs and enter a valid email in-case something went wrong.

Another reason I would use separate keys for your app/assets is different levels of trust.  I assume your images don't matter as much as your code/content and you will not be submitting forms to your users via the CDN, Server A may be onsite and Server B in public cloud on SSD.

Comment: Do you have any references or further information to back up your opinion? You can use the same private key and certificate on multiple servers easily. I agree though, option two would probably be slightly better, though either should work and option two reduces risk of revealing the private key.

Comment: absolutely either does work, if he's splitting the dependencies of his assets and apps, why wouldn't he split his ssl? :) and @Tim experience/opinion answer.

Comment: I agree that from security point of view, separate keys might be a better approach.  Can I only generate a Let's Encrypt SSL certificate containing only subdomain `cdn.exmaple.com`?  Or it must contains the root domain `example.com` as well?

Comment: I have separate certs for main and subdomains, so no  problem not to have main.

Answer (score 0):

Let's Encrypt now has wildcard certificate support, which I think would fit your use case the best.

The following Let's Encrypt blog post describes how to generate the wildcard certificate with Let's Encrypt DNS-01 challenge.

https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/acme-v2-production-environment-wildcards/55578